# Windowed functions and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pagination, sql-order-by

When running this statement I get the error `Windowed functions and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions.`

```
SELECT * FROM (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 'publishdate DESC') as RowNum,
* FROM news WHERE publishdate <=getdate()) as info
WHERE RowNum > 0 AND RowNum <= (100)
```

I want to use this statement to retrieve a resultset in a paged gridview.

How to get this statement to run?

Comment: Loose the single quotes on the ROW_NUMBER's ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY publishdate DESC) as RowNum,
* FROM news WHERE publishdate <=getdate()) as info
WHERE RowNum > 0 AND RowNum <= (100)
```

You dont need the `'` in (ORDER BY publishdate DESC)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I've also seen this error when asking for a page of data that doesn't exist (asking for more rows than exist in the db).